# Sandbox environment when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code

I hope everyone will understand my question.
So I'm using VSCode to do some python coding and I am a code -> debug -> code -> debug type of person so I would like to know if it is possible to activate some sort of sandbox environment when I debug.

For instance:

```
1  import numpy as np
2
3  a = np.linspace(0,1,10)
4  b = 5
5
6  c = a * b
7
8  for i in range(10):
9    d = c + a.T
```

Now say I add a breakpoint at line 9 and debug. When the debugger hits the breakpoint I want to be able to use variables `a, b and c` and also `numpy` in a different console environment. This will help me check things like *is the variable `d` doing what I want it to do* etc.

To those familiar with VScode something like the *Watch* bar in the debug window just more expandable.
[image: Watch bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a noob, like me, it's called the `DEBUG CONSOLE` and it's located at the bottom of your window:
[image]